# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist:

Tags: flutter, keytool

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\mohan.android\debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\mohan.android\debug.keystore

```
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:911)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:417)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:410)
```